# Suppress warning when R is spawn

Tags: r, linux

I'm working on R in a hosted server setting, and whenever I launch R, a warning message pops up:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

This is trivial and ignorable, but it bothers me when I use parallelization that spawns multiple R sessions that it quickly fills up the interface.

Is there a way to suppress the above message? Below is my info.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.3
```

Comment: Are you on WSL? Then this might be relevant https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379425/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate

Comment: I agree with AndreWildberg, I think it's more likely that this is OS-thing and not an "R" thing. I've seen it on WSL1, have not seen it on WSL2 (though I'm no longer using either), and have never seen it on any linux-based system.

Comment: @Wildberg Oh, no. I'm using a remote Linux server with SLURM scheduler.

Comment: @r2evans I agree it is more likely OS side, but I was wondering if there's way to suppress on R side.

Comment: Doesn't this warning emit before R starts?